# Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory Aborted

Tags: javascript, android

```js
const prompt = require('prompt-sync')();

const combosec = prompt('Type the file directory to use: ');

const output = prompt('type the file directory to be used as output: ');

const txt = XLSX.readFile(combosec);

XLSX.writeFile(txt,`/storage/emulated/0/Download/${output}.xls`);
```

Hello, I will convert txt file to xlsx file but I get the error in the title in termux application.

Comment: When using template literals, wrap the path with backticks, not with single quotes.

Comment: I'll try that too now it might be related to that too

Comment: no i get the same error anyway thank you